# ¿como llamar un metodo async en el contructor - C#?

Tags: c#, api, constructor, async

resulta que cree un proyecto en WPF para practicar el consumo de apis en C#. Asi que cree una clase que se llama `Conexion.cs` y quiero que apenas inicie el programa llame al servicio y cargue los datos. pero no se como llamar el metodo async de la clase `Conexion.cs` desde el metodo `MainWindows()` de la ventana principal del programa ya que el llamado al api es asincrono y el main no, pero si coloco asincrono en main tampoco deja.

CLASE CONEXION.CS (Tipo es el modelo de la consulta):

```
public class Conexion
{
     public async Task Get()
     {
         string url = $"{Constants.apiUrl}tipoController.php";
         var client = new HttpClient();
         var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(url);
         if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             var content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             List<Tipo> tipoList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Tipo>>(content);
         }
     }
 }
```

CLASE MAIN DEL `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Conexion con = new Conexion();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.con.Get(); //Aqui es donde quiero que una vez inicie el programa ejecute el metodo asincrono de la otra clase
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, practicamente a la fuerza y con mi propia logica. asi quedaron las clases:

`Conexion.cs`:

```
public class Conexion
{
    public async Task<List<Tipo>> Get()
    {
        List<Tipo> rpta = new List<Tipo>();
        string url = $"{Constants.apiUrl}tipoController.php";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            rpta = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Tipo>>(content);
        }
        return rpta;
    }
}
```

Clase de la ventana principal `MainWindows.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Conexion con = new Conexion();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Get();
     }

     public async void Get()
     {
         List<Tipo> consulta = await con.Get();
         MessageBox.Show("ok");
     }
}
```

Queda es ajustar variables y esas cosas